# Javascript prototyping reuse on multiple instances of the same class selector?

Tags: javascript

Say I have three `<div>` elements with a selector of `.js-hello` on, for example:

```
<div class="js-hello">...</div>
<div class="js-hello">...</div>
<div class="js-hello">...</div>
```

I want this to look like:

```
<div class="js-hello">Hello Foo!</div>
<div class="js-hello">Hello Foo!</div>
<div class="js-hello">Hello Foo!</div>
```

I now I have this vanilla JS (please, no jQuery)

```
;(function(root, factory) {
    if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['Hello'], function(Hello) {
            return (root.Hello = factory(Hello));
        });
    } else if(typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('carousel-js'));
    } else {
        root.Hello = factory(root.Hello);
    }
}(this, function() {

    'use strict';

    var Hello = function(el, name) {

        if (document.querySelector(el)) root.el = document.querySelector(el);
            else return;

        this.name = name;

        this.sayHello();
    };

    Hello.prototype.sayHello = function() {
        return this.el.innerHTML = 'Hello ' + this.name + '!';
    };

    return Hello;
}));
```

Finally, I want to invoke this prototypal 'plugin' **each time per selector** using the same selector, for example:

```
var hello = new Hello('.js-hello', 'Foo');
```

Now, I know `document.querySelector(el)` will only find the first element, but what I'm more interested in is being able to use it where ever `.js-hello` is found within the page. `document.querySelectorAll(...)` isn't quite the answer.

I'm trying to figure out how to do something similar to how MooTools would do an `each` loop on the element, for example ($$ being all elements matched):

```
$$('.js-hello').each(function(el) {
    return new Hello(el, 'Foo');
});
```

I can't quite wrap my head around it! Any help would be greatly appreciated or if someone could point me to a post that answers it, I've found zilch!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/80sn3j1b/2/

Comment: So, do you want one `Hello` instance per element, or one instance for all elements?

Comment: @Bergi, one instance per element, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> invoke the 'plugin' each time per selector using the same selector

That doesn't make sense, or at least is very bad design. Invoking a function with the same arguments should get you the same results, instead of using some internal, global counter that determines which of the many elements with that selector you're going to get.

Instead, you should follow that MooTools example more closely. Don't pass selectors to `Hello`, but elements, and do the selection outside of your constructor.

```
function Hello(el, name) {
    this.el = el;
    this.name = name;
    this.sayHello();
}
…

var els = document.querySelectorAll(".js-hello");
for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++)
    new Hello(els[i], "Foo");
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, this isn't by design (nor how it's done), think I've muddled words up a bit in there! This is working, in a sense, but I'm actually using this on a larger example. I have a carousel which when I click next/previous on the carousel controls, it is only working on the **first** carousel you action upon (click the navigation, for example) and non of the others. [See JSFiddle](http://codepen.io/JMDUK/pen/zxMjXY).

Comment: That's not a jsfiddle :-) Notice that your `currentIndex` is a global variable in that code. It should be instance-specific!

Comment: Oops, I normally use JSFiddle, It's because I had Sass so I needed to paste it somewhere haha! Food shout, thank you for the help. :-)